# array formula - count if - return unique/duplicated

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to convert this pull-down formula into an array formula:

=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,"Unique","Duplicated")

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A))=1,"Unique","Duplicated")))`